# Rewriting my url with htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, s3-rewrite-rules

Please help with rewriting url like this:

```
**/zanr/?f=akcija** to only **/akcija/** (GET value)
```

and I don't need this "/zanr/" part in urls...

Thank you!

Comment: please provide directory structure what you tried and where is this going to be used.

Comment: There are 800+ questions on [tag:friendly-url], how many have you gone through?

Comment: in root i have "zanr" folder and inside it index.php which is page that gives me all products from that category. and also i have another folder there "naslov" and that provides me a problem beacuse i have something like this http://localhost/film/zanr/?f=drama/naslov/?n=trka-zivota so product trka-zivota wont open the page because of this category "drama" (that folder doesnt exist)... this is something like 2 lvl get and i dont know hot to fix it